# How to start ipython notebook server at boot as daemon

Tags: python, ipython

I love ipython, especially the notebook feature. I currently keep a screen session running with the notebook process in it.  How would I add ipython's notebook engine/webserver to my system's (CentOS5) startup procedures?

Answer (score 12):

```
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/ipython-notebook.service
#put the following in there.
-----------------8<------------------
    [Unit]
    Description=IPython notebook

    [Service]
    Type=simple
    PIDFile=/var/run/ipython-notebook.pid
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/ipython notebook --no-browser
    User=ipynb
    Group=ipynb
    WorkingDirectory=/home/ipynb/notebooks

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
-----------------8<------------------

# useradd ipynb
# su - ipynb # go there create notebooks dir
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl enable ipython-notebook
# systemctl start ipython-notebook
```

[credits](https://amitksaha.wordpress.com/2013/09/22/managing-ipython-notebook-server-via-systemd-part-i)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe put something like:

```
cd /path/to/notebookdir && ipython notebook --no-browser &
```

in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`? That's the 'easy' way, fine I think if it's just your personal machine, but if it's a 'real' server you should probably do a full Sys V-init thing; see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26619/how-to-run-a-c-program-as-a-daemon) for more

Answer (score 3):

I assume you don't want to run the program as root. So this is my modified version that runs as `<username>` (put in `/etc/rc.local` before the `exit 0` line):

`su <username> -c "/usr/bin/ipython notebook --no-browser --profile <profilename> &"`

You can check to make sure your ipython is at that path with `which ipython`. Though you may just be able to get away with not putting the full path.

Comment: you may also want to specify the `--notebook-dir` option