# Running an IPython notebook server on EC2 instance start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to set up an EC2 instance running an ipython notebook server for personal data science projects. I can successfully get the server up and running, and access it from my browser, etc... I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 for my OS.

However, because I want to use a pretty big instance, it would get really expensive to leave it running all the time, so I want to be able to start and stop it when I don't need it. Currently, this means that I need to ssh into the instance and restart the server every time I start it up. I would like some way to run `ipython notebook --profile=nbserver` when the instance starts, so that I can start the instance an immediately access my server from my browser.

I put

```
#!/bin/bash
ipython notebook --profile=nbserver
```

in the user-data, but this doesn't appear to work. I'm unable to find a clear answer on whether user-data scripts are run only on first launch, or whenever the instance starts.

Is there another place I could put that script so that it would run whenever I start the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's what the AWS documentation says about cloudinit being at  launch or start](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), highlights mine:

> a set of cloud-init directives that executes **when the instance launches** ... Important: User data scripts and cloud-init directives **only run during the first boot cycle when an instance is launched**.

The easiest way to get something to start on every boot is to put lines in your `rc.local`. [Here's an example from a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298766/659298); certainly there are better ways to do it (so that, for instance, the notebook restarts itself if it dies for some reason), but that's enough to get started.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely read that section of the documentation, but I guess I just missed that one sentence.